# "See through" tooltips on Review Queues pages

Tags: bug

I've noticed today that there's some weird glitch on all Review Queues pages. This appeared today, I remember checking the review queues yesterday and it was fine. However, yesterday Windows updated itself so it might be related to that.

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 10.

```
Google Chrome   75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision    8d93477bd18154c67a70a67019cb8032382c55dd-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1160}
OS  Windows 10 OS Version 1709 (Build 16299.1268)
JavaScript  V8 7.5.288.30
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: It's on main Meta somewhere...and it's specific to Chrome as I recall.

Comment: The uber-Meta post is [Vertical lines seen on badge progress page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/313837)